# ESC/POS printer emulation

Tags: printing, command

I have some printer documentation and I don't understand the following text:

"The following lists all the commands for function management int ESC/POS Emulation of printer. The commands can be transmitted to the printer at any moment. "

[image: Here is the image of some commands]

Can anyone tell me how to run this commands? Any information will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: $xx means a single character with the value in hexadecimal.  So $1B is equivalent to the value 27 which is the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

What's your prog. language?

You just need to convert any char to ASCII code and send it to printer inside an array.

Each char of a word must be converted and there are ASCII codes for space, tab, cr, lf, bold, etc.

Comment: how about doing it with Javascript ?